# Mapping datatypes from SQLite dump file to Room entities

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have a `db.sqlite` dump file. When I view it in [SQLite Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) I can see that it contains many `CREATE TABLE, CREATE INDEX` statements. I'm using this dump file to create my Room Database by using `createFromAsset("db.sqlite")` function.

My question is, what is the correct way to map the datatypes in these tables from the dump file into the Kotlin datatypes in Room entities? Is there a rule for datatype mapping from SQLite dump file into Room entities? Is there an automated tool/library that can do it for me?

The types that SQLite Browser shows in these tables are quite broad:

```
date, datetime, mediumtext, varchar(255), varchar(32), tinyint(1), int(1), int(10), bigint(20), TEXT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an automated tool/library that can do it for me?

**No** (that I am aware of). I did have one BUT as Room started changing/adding features it became a nightmare AND its not that hard to convert. As will be shown below, Room can assist and make your life easier.

- Here's a link to the [project in github](https://github.com/Mike-j-t-laptop/RoomExistingSQLiteDBConverter), which has not been changed since December 2019

> My question is, what is the correct way to map the datatypes in these tables from the dump file into the Kotlin datatypes in Room entities? Is there a rule for datatype mapping from SQLite dump file into Room entities?

A column type will be one of four types INTEGER, TEXT, BLOB, or REAL. Only these types an be used. However, Room will generate these based upon the types when Room looks at the fields in the `@Entity` annotated classes.

- **Room does not cater for the default/drop through `NUMERIC` type**, IT CANNOT BE USED and must be converted.

1. A string will be converted to **TEXT**.
2. An integer type (e.g. `Long`, `Int`, `Byte` ....) will be converted to **INTEGER**.
3. A decimal type (e.g. `Double`, `Float` ....) will be converted to **REAL**
4. A byte stream, such as `ByteArray` will be converted to **BLOB**
5. more complex objects (e.g. Date) that are are not basically primitive types have to be converted to a primitive type or String (typically the latter as a JSON representation) OR the fields that make up the object can be added (possibly via an `@Embedded` annotation)

   1. by basically primitive type, this does not mean an actual primitive type as per Java int, long etc, but rather a type that Room knows will be one of the four column types above.

Now considering `date, datetime, mediumtext, varchar(255), varchar(32), tinyint(1), int(1), int(10), bigint(20), TEXT`

- date, you would need to look at how the date value is stored, is it a textual representation e.g. 2023-01-01 or is it an integer value? Respectively a field type of `String`  or `Long`.

  - if you use a Date type object e.g. `var mydate: Date` then you need a TypeConverter to Convert the date into either a Long/Int or a String (or even a ByteArray if wanted).
- datetime likewise.
- mediumtext, probably `String`
- varchar would very likely be `String`
- all the others very likely `Long` or `Int`
- Note. With the exception of a column defined as INTEGER that is the sole column of a PRIMARY KEY, SQLite can store any type in any column **BUT ROOM WILL NOT**.

Now the real issue you could encounter, is that if using createFromAsset that you will need to convert the asset.

The easiest way to do this is to first create the `@Entity` annotated classes, one per table based upon the above i.e. deciding what type of data is actually stored, as column names are very flexible in SQLite and also that you can store any type in any column (exception above), so it is the actual data that can be important.

- perhaps refer to [How flexible/restricive are SQLite column types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557278/how-flexible-restricive-are-sqlite-column-types)

When you have the proposed entities coded, then code an `@Database` annotated class with the entities parameter specifying the `@Entity` annotated classes. It could be as simple as, for example:-

```
@Database(entities = [Entity1::class,Entity2::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
}
```

- *Obviously the `@Entity` annotated classes would likely not be `Entity` and `Entity2`*

Now compile the project (successfully).

Room will then generate java that includes the SQL for creating the tables.

---

### **Example of The above** (based upon an assumed approximation of your various types):-

**Entity1** *for want of better names*:-

```
@Entity
data class Entity1(
    @PrimaryKey /* All entities MUST have a primary key */
    var datetime: Long=System.currentTimeMillis(), /* possible use */
    var date: String,
    var mediumtext: String,
    var varchar255: String?, /*<<<<<<<< nullable to demonstrate */
    var varchar32: String,
    var tinyint1: Short,
    var int1: Int,
    var int10: Int,
    var bigint20: Long /* Note BigInteger would need a type converter */
)
```

**The `@Database` annotated class**:-

```
@Database(entities = [Entity1::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
}
```

**Compile Successfully**

e.g.:-

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7s
34 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 26 up-to-date
```

From the Android View,

1. find the `java(generated)`, and then
2. the class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class suffixed with **Impl**, and then
3. the method name **createAllTables**

e.g.:-

[image]

From the above the `createAllTables` method is:-

```
  public void createAllTables(@NonNull final SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Entity1` (`datetime` INTEGER NOT NULL, `date` TEXT NOT NULL, `mediumtext` TEXT NOT NULL, `varchar255` TEXT, `varchar32` TEXT NOT NULL, `tinyint1` INTEGER NOT NULL, `int1` INTEGER NOT NULL, `int10` INTEGER NOT NULL, `bigint20` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`datetime`))");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, '142451a6629652e0eafe63b6637a32ff')");
  }
```

As can be seen Room converts types as described above **BUT** note that Room does more such as add NOT NULL constraints or not as in the case of the `varchar255` column.

- NOT NULL constraints must be as expected and additionally DEFAULT values must be as expected (i.e. if, for example, `@ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "whaetever")` where used then  `DEFAULT 'whaetever'` would be used)

  - if you need to convert data and no default value is specified the respective column definition in the asset must not have `DEFAULT ....`, this can complicate the copying of the data (step 3 below).

Room will only accept a database that has the definitions as per the generated SQL. If there are any discrepancies then the result will a be an exception that that lists what Room **Expected** and what was **Found**.

As such there is no doubt whatsoever, that the database copied from the assets needs to be changed (the only acceptable column type in your list is TEXT, every other column type would cause an exception).

You can either convert the database prior to it being copied into the assets folder or you can use the `PrepackagedDatabaseCallback`, example of its use can be found here [How do I use Room's prepackagedDatabaseCallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70141979/how-do-i-use-rooms-prepackageddatabasecallback)

I believe it is easier to use a tool such as SQLiteBrowser, in which case you could base the conversion upon:-

1. Use an `ALTER TABLE` to rename the original tables.
2. Create the tables using the generated SQL as obtained above.

   1. there is no need to bother with **room_master_table**, room will handle that.
3. Copy the data from the renamed original tables to their equivalents

   1. could be as simple as `INSERT INTO entity1 SELECT * FROM renamed_entity1`, it could be more complicated e.g. if you have nulls for a NOT NULL (perhaps add the `?` to the field, recompile and so on)
4. Delete the renamed tables using `DROP TABLE ....`
5. Perhaps consider doing a [`VACUUM`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html)
6. Save the database and then copy it into the assets folder
7. You can then complete the Room code (add the `@Dao` annotated interfaces, amend the `@Database` annotated class, add POJO's as required). If all has been done well, then the database should be opened and used successfully.

Comment: Indeed, I was getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema... Expected... Found...`, so I asked here. Now I understand that Room will accept only the TEXT datatype from my dump file, which I find to be very disheartening. Thank you for your detailed answer. I guess I'll have to manipulate the schema.

Comment: @gdrt Located the Conversion tool, its on github at https://github.com/Mike-j-t-laptop/RoomExistingSQLiteDBConverter. It only produces Java code though. As I said it is dated (4 years since).

Comment: Thank you MikeT. I'm accepting your answer. You can also add your comment into the answer.