# Pre Populating data in room database - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-jetpack

I have a room database configuration like below.
`Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDataBase::class.java, "wallet.db"       ).setQueryCallback(QueryInterceptor(), executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()         ).createFromAsset("attributes.db").build()`

I want to add some default pre-populated categories into an attributes table. Because user can also add or edit the present pre-populated data.

attributes.db has below queries.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attributes` (
    `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `key` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `value` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `meta_data` TEXT DEFAULT '',
    `isActive` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `attributes_in_detail` (`key`, `value`, `isActive`) VALUES (`essentials`, `Rent/mortgage`, 1);
```

I am not able to see the attributes.db queries getting run. Please help me how can I archive this in android room database.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would include data in the file using an external tool such  Navicat for SQLite, DB Browser for SQlite, DBeaver. This would include creating the tables, indexes and views according to the projects definition and then populating the data (e.g. the inserts).

Thus when the Room copies the file from the assets the database is populated (assuming the schema matches Room's expectations).

A file with SQL is not a pre-populated database and there is no handling with the `createFromAsset` method/function to execute SQL. In fact such a file would simply not adhere to Room's expectations.

If you wanted to use an asset, an externally created and likely populated database, and then execute SQL you could use the `PrepackagedDatabaseCallback` (2nd parameter of the `createFromAsset` invocation). This passes the copied database as a SupportSQLiteDatabase which can then be modified before Room opens the database.

A Java example of using this can be found at [How do I use Room's prepackagedDatabaseCallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70141979/how-do-i-use-rooms-prepackageddatabasecallback)

Other examples can be found by using the `android-room-prepackageddatabase` tag.